Problems connecting from PHP-FPM to DocumentDB after scaling the cluster down
My stack is as follows:

PHP application running in Docker containers on AWS EC2 instances

PHP-FPM 8.3.6
mongodb extension, ver 1.17.2
DoctrineODM as a DB abstraction layer


AWS DocumentDB cluster

My DocumentDB connection string is as follows:
mongodb://user:password@cluster-name.cluster-abcdefghijkl.eu-west-2.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/?tls=true&tlscafile=global-bundle.pem&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false

All of the above works perfectly well, until I remove one of the DocumentDB instances to scale the cluster down. After I do so, the application would always throw errors similar to ones below:
No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [Failed to resolve 'instance-name.abcdefghijkl.eu-west-2.docdb.amazonaws.com']

No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [socket timeout calling hello on 'instance-name.abcdefghijkl.eu-west-2.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017']

These errors would eventually go away after a couple of minutes if the removed instance was a secondary node. But when it was a primary (which then makes the other instance to became a new primary), the only reliable solution is to restart the PHP application.
Sometimes, out of nowhere the application throws errors similar to the below. I assume these can be caused by AWS moving some instances around and e.g. changing IP addresses:
No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [TLS handshake failed: Operation timed out calling hello on 'instance-name.abcdefghijkl.eu-west-2.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017']

I went through the documentation at https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.connection-handling.php and for me it looks like the default values of the connection configuration options should handle such situations within seconds. However for some reason it doesn't work very well in my case.
What can I do or change in order to eliminate the issue?
Side note. I connect to the same DocumentDB instances from other applications, e.g. ones running on AWS Lambda and I didn't see any problems similar to the one described above.
